# What's the recommended process for organising collaborative posting?

Tags: plugins, customization

The users over at [the scifi/fantasy SE site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) are getting our [blog](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com) organised.  We definitely need:

- To know who is writing (or planning to write) about what.
- What stage (planning, writing, needs-editing, needs-scheduling, scheduled, posted) each post is in.
- Who is currently working on the post (writing, editing).

We started out with a Google Docs spreadsheet, but although this was very free-form, it (a) didn't get well used, (b) doesn't have any integration with WordPress, and (c) doesn't have any notification system.

We recently switched to [Trello](http://trello.com) (our board is [here](https://trello.com/board/scifi-blogoverflow-com-schedule/4e71826f2256897d51319870)).  There are a lot of features we like here:

- Transparency.  Anyone (even people that aren't writing for the blog) can see what posts there are, and where everything fits in the schedule.  This is particularly important.
- It's quite flexible (a lot of different metadata can be attached to a post).
- It's easy to use and looks nice (which helps encourage people to use it).
- There's no real-name requirement.  If parts of the system are totally public (which we prefer) then this is a requirement.  If the system is only visible to writers/editors then we can live with real names, although we'd prefer not to.
- Email addresses aren't exposed.  Email addresses *are* exposed in WordPress (unfortunately), so this also isn't an issue for writers/editors, but we can't have email addresses exposed to the general public.

However, there are things that aren't so great:

- It's yet-another-account.  There's a StackExchange account, a WordPress account, and a Trello account to manage.  (This impacts on the real-name/email address issues from above, because an existing account may not be able to be used, and an email address is required to add an account).
- There are [notifications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/what-are-notifications-in-trello), but there's no documentation for them, so it's not obvious how to use them or exactly what you get notified about.
- There's no way to integrate with WordPress.  This means that whenever a post changes status, it has to be updated in WordPress *and* Trello.  This is made worse because as far as I can tell, WordPress doesn't notify anyone when a post moves to "Pending" (so if the change is made only in WordPress, no-one notices).

We're all new to collaborative blogging, but we know that other people have been doing this for ages.  What's the standard / best way of doing this sort of organisation?

If there's a WordPress plug-in that we can use to do everything inside of WordPress itself, we can probably get the StackExchange staff to install that.

Alternatively, is there a third-party site that offers much/all of what Trello does, but integrates better with WordPress?

Comment: Maybe you should try CollabPress - http://collabpress.org, I don't think that it's post oriented, but it has really good features for collaboration

Comment: Trello does have notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://editflow.org/ - a project launched by newsroom programmers.

It's something that addresses the entire editorial workflow, from scheduling to attribution.  Bonus: it now has WP Document Revisions integration.

Answer (score 0):

The only 3 I know of are:

[CollabPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/collabpress/)
[Ndizi Project Management](http://Ndizi%20Project%20Management)
[ProjectManager](http://ProjectManager)

Also check out http://p2theme.com/ you can make it private and work like a task manager, I hacked it a while back to also include photos and files.

I have not tried any of those plugins just fyi, it's still surprising they are not many more solutions or integrations since this type of functionality is in pretty high demand.

ps. Another solution (not out of the box) would be to use a service with a decent API and then send WordPress info to it using  [HookPress](http://mitcho.com/code/hookpress/).

Comment: Two of these links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

Similar (perhaps less robust) to Edit Flow, check out the Editorial Calendar plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/editorial-calendar/screenshots/

However, neither plugin would appear to have the interactive forum capabilities you appear to need. FWIW I did see bbPress now is a plugin and might be worth looking into, if you have not already.